# Reading out txt-files with fstream crashes .exe

Tags: c++, fstream

I am trying to read out a textfile containing data like this:

> 1 1 34.5 12.5 1 2 65.3 23.6 1 3 94.3 12.3

and so on, two integer numbers followed by two coordinates, rinse and repeat.
I use this code (I really don't know that much about programming):

```
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
vector<double> frame(1);
vector<double> point(1);
vector<double> PosX(1);
vector<double> PosY(1);
int i=0;
fstream file;
string line;
file.open ("sample1.txt", fstream::in | fstream::app);
while(getline(file, line))
{
    istringstream ss(line);
    ss >> frame[i] >> point[i] >> PosX[i] >> PosY[i];
    cout << frame[i] << " " << point[i] << " " << PosX[i] << " " << PosY[i]<< endl;
    i++;

}
return 0;
}
```

The program builds just fine and runs for about the first fifty sets of numbers, but then crashes.

Comment: Define "crashes". Learn to use a debugger.

Answer (score 2):

Your vectors only have one element each, but you're trying to set values for *way* more than that. No surprise it crashes — you're writing into memory you haven't allocated!

Use `push_back`, or `resize`, or make the vectors be of the correct size to begin with.

Comment: Thank you so much!!
Such a stupid mistake, I completely forgot about push_back.
It works now.
Thanks again!